# Table row into button in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

My question is the following: How do I make a table row into a button that can utilize `data-target`, so I can control for example a carousel. I want it so each row makes the carousel jump to a different picture.

Can anyone help me with this? I would really appreciate it.

I have some simple code for a carousel:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <!--Carousel-->
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-8">
            <div id="carousel" class="carousel" data-ride="carousel">
                <div class="carousel-inner" style="margin-bottom: -2%;">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <img class="d-block w-100" src="Bilder/Placeholder_Grundriss.jpg" alt="A1">
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img class="d-block w-100" src="Bilder/Placeholder_Grundriss2.jpg" alt="A2">
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img class="d-block w-100" src="Bilder/Placeholder_Grundriss.jpg" alt="B1">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and some simple Table

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <!--carousel End-->
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-10 " style="padding-top:5%;padding-bottom:5%;">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table-hover table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>bla</th>
                        <th>bla</th>
                        <th>bla</th>
                        <th>bla</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <body>
                    <tr>
                            <td>bla</td>
                            <td>bla</td>
                            <td>bla</td>
                            <td>bla</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                            <td>bla</td>
                            <td>bla</td>
                            <td>bla</td>
                            <td>bla</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                            <td>bla</td>
                            <td>bla</td>
                            <td>bla</td>
                            <td>bla</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                            <td>bla</td>
                            <td>bla</td>
                            <td>bla</td>
                            <td>bla</td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you considered adding a new cell containing a button to each row? That would be much more semantic and accessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't understand what you mean "how to make table row into a button?".
I just understood you want to control picture of `carousel` with table row. You can add `data-target` and `data-slide-to` attributes to table row and on clicking on table row, picture of carousel will be changed.
You can do as follows:

```
<tr data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0">
     <td>bla</td>
     <td>bla</td>
     <td>bla</td>
     <td>bla</td>
 </tr>
 <tr data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1">
      <td>bla</td>
      <td>bla</td>
      <td>bla</td>
      <td>bla</td>
 </tr>
 <tr data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2">
      <td>bla</td>
      <td>bla</td>
      <td>bla</td>
      <td>bla</td>
 </tr>
 <tr  data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1">
      <td>bla</td>
      <td>bla</td>
      <td>bla</td>
      <td>bla</td>
</tr>
```

On click of table row, data-slide-to will show image of your carousel whatever image number you will provide.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was exactly was I was looking for!